# Is it possible to refactor the vanilla JS DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, refactoring, destructuring

I am wondering if it is possible to refactor the following code in a clean and nice way to avoid the repetition at each and every is statement:

```
if (statement) {
    menu.style.display = "inline-block";
    emoji.style.display = "inline-block";
    del.style.display = "block";
    upload.style.display = "block";
} else if (statement) {
    menu.style.display = "none";
    emoji.style.display = "inline-block";
    del.style.display = "none";
    upload.style.display = "none";
} else {
    menu.style.display = "none";
    emoji.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    upload.style.display = "none";
}
```

I know i can do object destructuring but i also want to reduce the number of lines because i have this peace of code repeated many times in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to make an array of the elements, and set all their styles to `none` regardless, then inside the conditions, set styles that *aren't* going to be `none`:

```
[menu, emoji, del, upload].forEach(elm => elm.style.display = "none");
if (statement) {
  menu.style.display = "inline-block";
  emoji.style.display = "inline-block";
} else if (statement) {
  emoji.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

If you frequently have multiple elements that you want to change the style of, consider a function:

```
const setAllDisplays = (display, ...elms) => elms.forEach(elm => elm.style.display = display);
setAllDisplays('none', menu, emoji, del, upload);
if (statement) {
  setAllDisplays("inline-block", menu, emoji);
} else if (statement) {
  emoji.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

Comment: I think in your 2nd code snippet you meant to say : `elm.style.display = display` inside your foreach

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain an object with the wanted states for each target and get the index and update the targets.

```
var display = {
        menu: ["inline-block", "none", "none"],
        emoji: ["inline-block", "inline-block", "none"],
        del: ["block", "none", "none"],
        upload: ["block", "none", "none"],
        reference: { menu, emoji, del, upload }
    },
    index = statement ? 0 : statement ? 1 : 2;

Object.keys(display).forEach(k => reference[k].stype.display = display[k][index]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nina, your solution is awesome too.

Answer (score 0):

"...because i have this peace of code repeated many times in my code."

So just make it into a function, and keep it exactly as it is now:

```
function(condition1, condition2, menu, emoji, del, upload){
  if (condition1) {
    menu.style.display = "inline-block";
    emoji.style.display = "inline-block";
    del.style.display = "block";
    upload.style.display = "block";
  } else if (condition2) {
    menu.style.display = "none";
    emoji.style.display = "inline-block";
    del.style.display = "none";
    upload.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    menu.style.display = "none";
    emoji.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    upload.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Then you can just call the function from anywhere with any condition1 and condition2

Comment: Thanks @TKOL, I have this piece of code is it is, but with different displays every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing it like this:

```
container.classList.remove("one", "two", "three");
if (expression) {
    container.classList.add("one");
} else if (expression) {
    container.classList.add("two");
} else {
    container.classList.add("three");
}
```

...inside a reusable function, where `container` is the nearest element that contains `menu`, `emoji`, `del`, and `upload` (in the worst case it's `body`). Then style the individual elements via CSS, e.g.:

```
.one menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
.two menu, .three menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Obviously, instead of `"one"`, `"two"`, and `"three"` you'd use names that reflect the state.

---

Depending on what the expressions are, you might be able to use this code instead of the `if`/`else if`/`else` above:

```
container.classList.toggle("one", expression);
container.classList.toggle("two", expression);
container.classList.toggle("three", expression);
```